# ReferenceError: err is not defined in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

why is that **ReferenceError: err is not defined** even though it is defined here?

```
const sampleObject = require('./sampleObject');

const sampleModel = (callback) => {
    if (true) {
        sampleObject.sampleRetrieval(err, data => {
            if (err) {
                callback(err)
            } else {
                callback(data)
            }
        })

    } else {
        console.log('Something went wrong.');
    }
}

module.exports = sampleModel;
```

This is the file that executes the query and passes it to the sampleModel.

```
const myDB = require('../db/database');
module.exports = {
    sampleRetrieval: () => {
        let sql = "SELECT * FROM ACCOUNTS";
        myDB.query(sql, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                callback(null, err)

            } else {
                callback(err, data)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: you're missing parentheses around the arguments to your fat-arrow function.  `err, data =>` is not the same thing as `(err, data) =>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your function **sampleRetrieval** is not receiving a callback function as a parameter. It should be something like this:

```
sampleRetrieval: (callback) => {
    let sql = "SELECT * FROM ACCOUNTS";
    myDB.query(sql, (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            callback(null, err);
        } else {
            callback(err, data);
        }
    })
}
```

And then fix the parentheses like the comment of Dan O says:

```
const sampleModel = (callback) => {
    if (true) {
        sampleObject.sampleRetrieval((err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                callback(err)
            } else {
                callback(data)
            }
        })
    } else {
        console.log('Something went wrong.');
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Error : err is not defined

```
newUser.save()
.then( ()=> res.json('User added!'))
.catch( err => res.status(400).json('Error: '+ err));
```

Fixed

```
newUser.save()
    .then( ()=> res.json('User added!'))
    .catch( (err) => res.status(400).json('Error: '+ err));
```